# VBA script to move/combine attachments on items in MS Access into a single folder

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created a table in MS Access and every item in my table will have an attachment, an image or word doc file.

I wish to create a VBA script that when my data items are filtered, I could move all the attachments on the items that are left get moved into a folder on my local device.

Comment: Review https://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/working-with-attachment-fields.html

Comment: here is another example of  saving attachments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/field2-savetofile-method-dao  Here is an example of iterating through a filtered recordset.  In your case grab the filter from the forms filter:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-filter-property-dao